# needing storage integrity (write/read) test - for BASH

Tags: linux, bash, storage

In need of shell scripts / bash commands to **verify data integrity of local harddrives, usb-drives,** etc, ...

Like the famous [www.heise.de/download/h2testw](http://www.heise.de/download/h2testw); or something that is at least common within repositories.
 *(h2testw writes a specific datastring over and over onto the medium, then reads it again to verify if it was written correctly and displays write/read time/speed.)*

please no

```
 dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdx bs=1k && dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/null bs=1k
```

since it won't verify if everything was written correctly. It is only a test if read/write is successful to the device.

So far, I'm not too happy with

```
badblocks -w -v /dev/sdx1
```

either, since it seems rather slow and I don't know what it exactly writes, and if it considers wear-leveling on flash media.

There is also a program named F3 http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/ that needs to be compiled. Designed after h2testw, the concept sounds interesting, i'd just rather have it as a ready to go bash script.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Cross-posting is strongly discouraged -- if you post on one site and then change your mind it can always be migrated to another.

Comment: @uther I'm sorry, i didn't know. I thought my chances to get an alternative answer would get better. If I'm not 100% happy with an answer, is it okay to not accept, even if it works? How do i improve my chances for another answer without setting up a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

This is not bash, but `badblocks` is quite popular tool for testing hard drives under *nix, and pretty much as ubiquitous as `dd`.

From [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks):

> -w     Use  write-mode test. With this option, badblocks scans for bad blocks by  writing some patterns (0xaa, 0x55, 0xff, 0x00) on every
>   block of the device, reading every block and comparing the contents. 
>   This option may not be combined with the -n option, as they are
>   mutually exclusive.

You can also run non-destructive (`-n`) read-write test.

Comment: do i need to add a specific block size via `-b` option for flash media? keyword: **wear leveling?** and does bash only mean internal bash functions? thanks so far.

Comment: @Mr.Bash As far as I know, it is necessary to alter block size only f you are going to use `badblocks` output in `mke3fs`, otherwise there is no big difference. `badblocks` does not consider internal device way of mapping physical blocks to virtual ones (such as wear-leveling of flash drives), so no luck here.